# Grub repair on a system with legacy bios but GPT partitioned disk?

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, uefi, 17.10

i have a xubuntu 17.10 installation on a hard drive partitioned with GPT but with a legacy BIOS and i want to repair grub i have tried the following in chroot

`grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda`

i have also tried

`grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /boot/efi`

even thought the process completes with no errors, i still can't boot my os, please help

**thank you**

Comment: did you install the grub-efi package?

Comment: i have tried both grub-efi and grub-pc

Comment: you need grub-efi. does the computer support EFI boot? and do `grub-install --uefi-secure-boot`

Comment: If BIOS booting, you do not want nor need grub-efi-amd64. You want grub-pc. But must have the bios_grub partition as in ubfan1 answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have  a legacy BIOS, and a gpt partitioned disk, you need some place on the disk for the legacy grub bootloader, which can no longer squeeze between the partitions like on an MSDOS partitioned disk.  That place is a 1-2M unformatted partition with the bios-grub flag.  Then grub-pc should install successfully.